# Center content block on a printed page

Tags: html, css, printing

I am converting some old, hand generated printouts to dynamically created ones that work in the browser and print. They have a sidebar and multiple pages (usually) of content. The content is broken into sections that avoid page breaks.

My html structure looks something like this, but with more sections and figures:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <article class="col-md-push-3 col-md-9">
            <img class="pull-right img-responsive logo" src="http://adm25512/factsheet/images/logo.jpg" />
            <section>
                <h2>Content section title</h2>
                <p>Lots of content in here - sometimes more than a page.</p>
                <figure>
                    <img src="coolimg.png" alt="accessibility"/>
                    <figcaption>What a cool image!</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h2>There are several sections of varying lengths</h2>
                <p>Content</p>
            </section>
        </article>
        <aside class="sidebar col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs"> 
            <section>
                <h4>There's only one section over here</h4>
                <p>Content</p>
            </section>
            <figure>
                <img src="coolimg2.png" alt="accessibility"/>
                <figcaption>But a lot of figures</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the relevant bit of CSS:

```
section:nth-of-type(n+2), figure { /* n+2 because we want the first one to be on the first page regardless of whether the header pushes it onto the next page. */
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}

aside {
    float:left;
    width:33vw;
    background-color:#eee;
    padding:0;
    min-height:100%;
}

article {
    float:right;
    width:60vw;
    margin-left:2vw;
}
```

**What I want is for the sections that display on each page to center themselves vertically on that page** - for example, if I have a section that's only 10 lines, it should be in the middle of the printed page. I tried this, but it didn't work, which was expected.

```
@page {
    min-height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

And a handy image showing what I want to accomplish:

[image: center an image on a printed page]

Other notes: I'm not using bootstrap or anything else in the print stylesheet and the print layout is treated differently from the web layout. So there won't be any collisions between rules. I would be ok with javascript as a solution if there were a way to reliably trigger it before printing and undo it after the print is sent - i.e. it doesn't break stuff in the browser.

Comment: I think you need to put `display:flex` on an element, not the overall page. Also, I think `@page` is only support in a print media query.

Comment: @aardrian `@ page` works fine outside of a media query - I can style each page and do things like margins and padding. And I believe I need to treat the `page box` as an element to style its contents.